# DexIndexOverflowException when running androidTests

Tags: android, android-testing, android-multidex

when running ./gradlew clean connectedWithAnalyticsWithCloudDebugAndroidTest I am getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithDexForWithAnalyticsWithCloudDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

but on the app-side I am safe: ./gradlew clean assembleWithAnalyticsWithCloudRelease ends in:

```
Total methods in Gobandroid-2.4.1-withAnalytics-withCloud-release-unsigned.apk: 31976 (48.79% used)
Total fields in Gobandroid-2.4.1-withAnalytics-withCloud-release-unsigned.apk:  14955 (22.82% used)
Methods remaining in Gobandroid-2.4.1-withAnalytics-withCloud-release-unsigned.apk: 33559
Fields remaining in Gobandroid-2.4.1-withAnalytics-withCloud-release-unsigned.apk:  50580

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I do not want to activate multidex as it is not needed for the app - but I would like to run my tests. Is there a good way to enable multidex only for the tests?

Comment: it should be possible having a manifest file under `src/androidTest` and the manifest merger should take care of it. It should be also possible to use `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` to add the dependency only for android tests. The only missing piece is how to change  multiDexEnabled to true only during tests (Assuming that the other steps work)

Comment: I want to add in @Blackbelt's comment. Can we enable multidex for test in `build.gradle` like this: `android {
  defaultConfig {
      ...
      testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
  }
}`. See [Testing Multidex Apps](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#testing)